# GLMM for SNA and non-independency data

Tags: glmm, independence, social-network

I contact you because my case is particular and I don’t know much about GLMM.
I have data of social networks (network metrics) of a nonhuman primate species. These data are by nature non independent (behaviour between A and B can influence those of C). I also have individual attributes (gender, age, kinship and hierarchical rank).
I would like to test the effect of individual attributes on the network metrics. For this purpose I have to take into count the non-independency of data (I could make link filtering or permutation test but I am trying something new). I was thinking about doing a General Linear Mixed Model (GLMM) including individuals as random factors. I see that this analysis can take into count the non-independency of data, but I only see this test for multiple measures on same individuals (which is another kind of non-independency) and not for a single measure on individuals. Do you think even if this is not the same type of non-independency data GLMM can take into count my type of data?

Regards

---

Thank you for your answer. I watched p model but it seems that this method needs binary networks. I also know MRQAP or QAP analysis but as for p model they correlate networks with indiviudal attributes and not network metrics with attributes.
I also know anova and t-test with permutation performed on ucinet but I would like to  use a new protocol and I think GLMM can make up with independent data. This idea emerges from Darren Croft's paper 'Hypothesis testing in animal social networks' in which he says:
'Model fitting is a potentially different approach to hypothesis testing. In particular, mixed models can account for some forms of data non-independence and have already been applied to the analyses of animal social networks'.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either [p*/Exponential Random Graph Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_random_graph_model) or Quadratic Assignment Procedure tests over GLMM. Those methods are made especially for the data you have available.